# Using "if" in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm writing a repeating payments migration tool for moving from one payment system to another.  All of the users' credit card and bank information is stored on those systems, so I need users to reenter the information, as I don't have it stored in my own database.

Users can either update their information or choose to delete their recurring payment and not migrate it to the new system.  My migration data object includes an enum called `UpdateAction` with values `Delete` and `Update`.

I'm writing a review-your-input page and have a `ListView` control with an item template that displays all the information.  When the action is to delete, there's no other information to display, so I have:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvReview" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><b><%# Eval("PaymentProfileName") %></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Action</td><td><%# Eval("Action").ToString() %></td></tr>
<%  if ((UpdateAction)Eval("UpdateAction") == UpdateAction.Update) 
    { %>
        <!-- Update item bound content here -->
<%  } %>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

This doesn't work because you have to use `<%# ... %>` in order to use Eval(), in which case, you can't use the `if`.  Is there a way to reference the data item being bound in the ascx file itself?  Or must I make a bunch of literal controls and put my `if` in a `OnItemDataBound` event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with the OnItemDataBound event.  Put your Update item bound content in a panel that you can set it's visiblity...

```
UpdateAction action = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "UpdateAction");
if (action == UpdateAction.Update)
{
    pnlUpdateItems.Visible = true;
}
else
{    
    pnlUpdateItems.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I had to use a `PlaceHolder` rather than a `Panel` because it was within a table, but this is basically how to do it.  Thanks!